# What do the 'Custom shape' options on the Sapling Tree Gen add-on do?

Tags: modeling, add-on, sapling-addon

I downloaded Sapling Tree Gen 2.78 and I can't find any help.

What do the 4 lines of *Custom Shape* mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you change *shape* to *custom shape*, these values will be active.

When you point your mouse on it it says these are the values for *Base*, *Middle*, *Middle position* and *Top* respectively. You can change those, using your mouse and drag these fields to the left or right or enter number between 0.01 and 1

[image]

Comment: Why are you editing my answer, i think you want to edit your question?

Comment: to add pictures

Comment: Yes I want it but when i add comment I can't attach pictures. I am sorry

Comment: I can delete it if you want.

Comment: it's okay :) you can add it in your question under 'edit'

Comment: I am sorry I have to go out. I will contact you tomorrow. Many thanks

Comment: @FacebFaceb If you type ``[edit]`` it will render as [edit] which, when clicked on, takes you to the question in 'edit' mode. It can be useful to give to users who may not know how to edit questions.

Comment: @RayMairlot thanks, but the user knows how to edit my answer though

Comment: Yes, but they didn't know how to edit their own, which was my point. That link takes them to *their* question.

Comment: @RayMairlot ok, i changed it to [ edit ], but it doesn't link. Btw, how can you use bold, or letters like your '[ edit ]'?

Comment: There are no spaces between the words and the square brackets. Code formatting is 'backticks' ( ` ) surrounding the word.

Comment: I mean I have added '[ edit ]' to the OP's question, or should i do it as comment under their question? I did intended to type '[ edit ]' instead of [edit], because the latter won't show the brackets and I wanted to ask about the syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50459/discussion-between-ray-mairlot-and-faceb-faceb).